# swf in Desktop Java programs

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, flash

How to use & show swf files in Desktop Java programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple opensource / free options, but the first one
https://jflash.dev.java.net/
is not being maintained any longer. The one you want to look into is from Joa Ebert and is called JITB, see it in-action here http://blog.joa-ebert.com/2010/08/19/introducing-jitb/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jpackages.com/jflashplayer/ is the most standard approach.

Comment: You should be aware this is not a FREE option.

Comment: Thanks, it's very useful.But i'm searching for FREE API.